# Entity Framework - Return multiple columns on insert / update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I insert entity object to the context or update it, Entity Framework generates query with `RETURNING` clause pointing to the primary key.

Pseudo code:

```
class Job {
    //Primary key
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    //Identifier generated via "before insert" postgresql trigger
    public string JobIdentifier { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

using (var context = CreateEFContext())
{
    var job = new Job() {
        Name = "test job",
    }
    context.Job.Add(job);
    context.SaveChanges();
    
    //the job identifier is empty
    var generatedJobIdentifier = job.JobIdentifier;
}
```

Above code will return only `ID` column via `RETURNING` clause on `INSERT` query, but I'm interested in both `ID` and `JobIdentifier` values without calling another query just moment after update or insert.
My question is how could I instruct Entity Framework to return multiple columns on `INSERT` query via some additional settings?

Comment: `job` object can contain any (amount) of properties, so why do you say only 1 column is returned?

Comment: @LeiYang Entity by default only returns primary key - ID is primary key, so it's returned. The question is how can I instruct Entity to return more columns than just primary key.

Comment: Just query the db for the correct values. An insert statement always returns the PK of the item that has just been inserted.

Comment: it sounds reasonable, for performance reasons consideration, at least. i once knew ado.net can call stored procedure, with which you can specify any amount of out parameters.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane postgresql have native functionality of `RETURNING` multiple columns on insert. Does entity framework have it too?

Comment: @LeiYang according to the postgresql documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html "Thus, inspecting columns computed by triggers is another common use-case for RETURNING." - it's reasonable to use `RETURNING` to get column generated by trigger than querying `SELECT` just after `INSERT`.

Comment: your feature request sounds reasonable too(maybe github is a better place). but since the library cannot be changed so soon, can you try measure the performance, between only insert the object, and insert and query in same tracsaction?